# How to restart My Mediaplayer and Play new PlayList if my service is running in background

Tags: android

My player is working through service and i want to play another PlayList i used broadcast but it's not working properly and i update my seekbar using service it's also not updating properly.

```
if (mApp.ismIsServiceRunning() == true) {
                mApp.getService().mediaPlayer.stop();

                new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).clearCachedAudioPlaylist();

                track_title.setText(trackArrayList.get(0).getTrk_title());
                art_name.setText(trackArrayList.get(0).getArt_name());
                track_id = trackArrayList.get(0).getTrk_id();


                if (trackArrayList.get(0).getFavourite_status().equals("false")) {
                    favrit.setImageResource(R.mipmap.fav);
                } else {
                    favrit.setImageResource(R.mipmap.fav_fill);
                }

                StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
                storage.storeAudio(trackArrayList);
                storage.storeAudioIndex(0);

                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
                sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
```

My Service is like this

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{

    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder iBinder = new LocalBinder();

    //List of available Audio files
    private ArrayList<Track> audioList;
    private int audioIndex = -1;
    private Track activeAudio; //an object on the currently playing audio


    //Handle incoming phone calls
    private boolean ongoingCall = false;
    private PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;
    private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;


    /**
     * Service lifecycle methods
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        register_playNewAudio();

    }

    //The system calls this method when an activity, requests the service be started
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



        try {

            //Load data from SharedPreferences
            StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
            audioList = storage.loadAudio();
            audioIndex = storage.loadAudioIndex();


        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            stopSelf();
        }

        //Request audio focus
        if (requestAudioFocus() == false) {
            //Could not gain focus
            stopSelf();
        }


        if (mediaSessionManager == null) {
            try {
                initMediaSession();
                initMediaPlayer();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                stopSelf();
            }
        }

        //Handle Intent action from MediaSession.TransportControls
        handleIncomingActions(intent);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        mediaSession.release();
        removeNotification();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            stopMedia();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }

        new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).clearCachedAudioPlaylist();
    }


    /**
     * Service Binder
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MediaPlayerService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return MediaPlayerService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        //Invoked to communicate some info
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //Invoked when the media source is ready for playback.
        playMedia();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //Invoked indicating the completion of a seek operation.
    }

    /**
     * MediaPlayer actions
     */
    private void initMediaPlayer() {
        if (mediaPlayer == null)
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();//new MediaPlayer instance

        //Set up MediaPlayer event listeners
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        //Reset so that the MediaPlayer is not pointing to another data source
        mediaPlayer.reset();


        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            // Set the data source to the mediaFile location
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioList.get(audioIndex).getTrk_audio());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            stopSelf();
        }

        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }

    private void playMedia() {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
          //  mLocalBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext);
           // mLocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent_brodcast_seekbar);
        }
    }

    private void stopMedia() {
        if (mediaPlayer == null) return;
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    }

    public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
        return mediaPlayer;
    }



    /**
     * Play new Audio
     */
    private BroadcastReceiver playNewAudio = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            audioList.clear();

            audioList = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).loadAudio();
            audioIndex = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).loadAudioIndex();
            stopMedia();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            initMediaPlayer();

        }
    };

    private void register_playNewAudio() {
        //Register playNewMedia receiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PlaylistActivity.Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
        registerReceiver(playNewAudio, filter);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a background music service project in my book.
Here is how I layed it out. I did not include the binding code to bind the service to the app, but seems you have that correct.

First, in the Main controlling Activity, there are buttons which can play, pause and seek forward 60 secondsin the song. Those button handlers look like this in the MainActivity.

```
// Set Button handlers
((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);      

// Add a long click listener on the Start button which will seek forward 30 seconds
((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnLongClickListener(longClick);
```

And the button handlers also in the MainActivity:

```
private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnStart:{
                enableButtons(true);
                mServ.resumeMusic();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.btnStop:{
                enableButtons(false);
                mServ.pauseMusic();
                break;
            }               
        }
    }
};

private View.OnLongClickListener longClick = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        mServ.forwardMusic();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Forwarding 60 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
};
```

Then in the service, you implement the actions accordingly:

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener{

    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder(); 
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private int length = 0;
    private int seekForwardTime = 60000;

    public MusicService() { } 

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
         public MusicService getServiceInstance() {
            return MusicService.this;
         }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0){return mBinder;}

    @Override
    public void onCreate () {
        super.onCreate(); 
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yoursongname);
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

        if(mPlayer!= null) {
            mPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mPlayer.setVolume(100,100);
        }
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         mPlayer.start();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;

    }

    public void pauseMusic() {
        if(mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            length=mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();        
        }
    }

    public void forwardMusic() {
        if(mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            int currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
            if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mPlayer.getDuration()) {
                // forward song
                mPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
            }
        }
    }

    public void resumeMusic() {
        if(mPlayer.isPlaying()==false)
        {
            mPlayer.seekTo(length);
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    public void stopMusic() {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy () {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {   
        Toast.makeText(this, "music player failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        if(mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this could help. Mark Wickham

Comment: Hey Wickham thax for your answer I appreciate it. But i also want to update my seekbar of mediaplayer through service can you give suggestion.

Comment: Hey Kishan, well, at a high level, I would say you implement your seekbar in your activity. You may also add 'skip forward' and 'skip backward' arrows to the right and left of the seek bar. The code I gave for forwardMusic() could be used for the skip forward arrow. You can implement similar for the skip backward. To allow your user to drag the seekbar, you could implement an onProgressUpdate method on the seekbar and pass the position to the service.

Comment: Hey Wickham thanx for your precious time for the comment,When i play next song my songs are skipping and it is not play in proper order when i try to update my seek bar from the service like this.
private void playMedia() {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mLocalBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext);
            mLocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent_brodcast_seekbar);
        }
    }

but if i remove broadcast for update seekbar my can maintain proper order of songs.

Comment: Hey Kishan,  I am not really seeing your issue as I look at the code you pasted. I would suggest that the broadcast receiver inside the service may not be necessary. You seem to have an ArrayList of the songs and are using SharedPrefs to store them. That should be ok. When the seek bar gets moved by the user, that should fire an update into your service and should not cuase the songs to get skipped, just reposition on the current song. You can use onProgressUpdate on the seekBar and this does not require a broadcast receiver. You just have to notify the service of the new position.